# Dynamic URL rewriting via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo

My URLs need to be dynamically changed from:

```
https://www.example.com/webshop/recipe/Actimel-Breakfast-Lollies/145794?recipeId=145794&site=desktop
https://www.example.com/webshop/recipe/Actimel-Breakfast-Lollies/145794?selectedCategories=1087
https://www.example.com/webshop/recipe/Actimel-Breakfast-Lollies/145794?selectedCategories=1088
https://www.example.com/webshop/recipe/Actimel-Breakfast-Lollies/145794?selectedCategories=1090
https://www.example.com/webshop/recipe/Actimel-Breakfast-Lollies/145794?selectedCategories=2262
https://www.example.com/webshop/recipe/Actimel-Breakfast-Lollies/145794?selectedCategories=31246
https://www.example.com/webshop/recipe/Actimel-Breakfast-Lollies/145794?selectedCategories=40778
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com/webshop/recipe/actimel-breakfast-lollies/145794
```

Its a bespoke website, so it there anyway in `.htaccess` to remove anything after the `?selected` and so on please?

Comment: Is the query string not required at all? You are presumably already linking to the canonical URL without a query string throughout your site?

Comment: ...and what have you tried? What other directives do you have in `.htaccess`? ANy other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: In my eyes it is completely unclear what you actually ask. What does "it there anyway ... to remove anything after the ?selected and so on" actually mean? Remove it where, in the link handed out to clients or in incoming requests from clients?

Comment: Basically, I just want the naked URL without the query, so it's removed.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, I just want the naked URL without the query, so it's removed.

In that case you would need an external redirect to remove the query string and lowercase the URL.

The following would redirect the stated URLs in your example. This would need to go near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^webshop/recipe/Actimel-Breakfast-Lollies/145794$ /webshop/recipe/actimel-breakfast-lollies/145794 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `QSD` flag discards the original query string from the request.

This assumes you are already internally linking to the canonical URL without a query string (ie. `/webshop/recipe/actimel-breakfast-lollies/145794`).

(But this is not "dynamic URL rewriting" as stated in your question title.)